# Find xpaths and extract text & status of checkbox/radio buttons in a loop

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a page where I need to extract the text from an xpath and the status of the radio or checkbox that is associated with the text.
Each element is contained in a class called "c-form-group", so i have written a loop to iterate through to extract the "Text" the will be 4 elements found on the page. But it is failing on element 3 & 4, i must have something wrong with my xpath. I have yet to add in the check for the checkbox/radio button,

The first two elements are returning the values i require, then fails on element3.

Here are the 4 text elements i am trying to extract:

Plan B Warranty (Taxi) & Breakdown Recovery

Vehicle Asset Protection - Standard Cover

Negative Equity Cover

You confirm that you have received the VAP key facts leaflet?

Here is the code for the loop.

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.className("c-form-group"));
System.out.println("a");    
List<WebElement> elementz =  elem.findElements(By.xpath("//label[contains(@class,'c-option')]"));

for(int i = 0 ; i< elementz.size() ; i++){
    System.out.println("Loop : " + i);   
     String vapval1 = elementz.get(i).findElement(By.xpath("//label[@class='c-option c-option--right u-px u-py-sm u-clearfix ng-scope' and not(@class='ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-required') and not (@class='c-option__radio')]")).getText();
     System.out.println("0 = " + vapval1);
     String vapval2 = elementz.get(i).findElement(By.xpath("//label[@class='c-option c-option--right u-px u-py-sm u-clearfix' and not(@class='ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-required') and not (@class='c-option__radio')]")).getText();
     System.out.println("1 = " + vapval2);
     String vapval3 = elementz.get(i).findElement(By.xpath("//label[@class,'c-option c-option--right u-px u-py-sm u-clearfix ng-scope' and not(@class='ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid') and not (@class='c-option__checkbox')]")).getText();
     System.out.println("3 = " + vapval3);
     String vapval4 = elementz.get(i).findElement(By.xpath("//label[@class,'c-option c-option--right u-px u-py-sm u-clearfix' and not(@class='ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-required') and not (@class='c-option__checkbox')]")).getText();
     System.out.println("4 = " + vapval4);
    }
```

Here is the full html, which may help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="ng-scope" ng-app="dan">
<head>
<body class="u-scroll-y ng-scope" ng-controller="CoreController as cc">
<div class="c-animate c-animate--show u-pos-f-t ng-hide" ng-show="global.alerts.length">
<div class="o-grid-fluid u-h-100 u-pl-0">
<div class="o-grid__row u-ml-0 u-h-100">
<div class="c-loader ng-hide" ng-show="loadingHome" style="">
<nav class="o-grid__col-xl-2 o-grid__col-lg-3 o-grid__col-xs-4 u-p-0 c-card__block u-h-100 u-shadowed u-pos-f-t ng-scope" ng-if="global.loggedIn">
<div class="u-p-0 u-h-100 o-grid__col-xl-10 o-grid__col-lg-9 o-grid__col-xs-8 u-pull-right" ng-class="{ 'o-grid__col-xl-10 o-grid__col-lg-9 o-grid__col-xs-8 u-pull-right' : global.loggedIn }">
<header class="o-layout-table__row u-bg-primary u-shadowed u-clearfix u-px ng-scope" ng-if="global.loggedIn">
<main class="o-view-container">
<div class="o-grid-fluid u-py-md">
<div class="o-grid__row">
<div class="c-animate c-animate--view-slide-in-right c-animate--view-slide-out-right ng-scope" ng-view="" style="">
<div class="o-grid__col-md-10 o-grid__col-xl-8 o-grid__col-xl-offset-2 o-grid__col-md-offset-1 ng-scope">
<div class="u-mb-lg u-text-center">
<h1 class="u-text-bold">Recommendations</h1>
</div>
<form class="ng-valid ng-valid-min ng-valid-max ng-valid-required ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" name="recommend" ng-submit="recommend.$valid" style="">
<div class="o-media c-card c-card__block u-shadowed u-mb-lg ng-scope" ng-if="rc.WarrantyEligible && !rc.prevWarranty()">
<label class="c-form-control-label u-px u-py-sm u-w-100">Warranty Options:</label>
<div class="c-form-group u-p-0 u-mb-sm u-clearfix">
<div class="o-grid__col-md-8">
<label class="c-form-control-label u-text-normal">Product Recommendations (Years):</label>
</div>
<div class="o-grid__col-md-4">
<input class="c-form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-min ng-valid-max ng-valid-required" required="" placeholder="Years" ng-model="rc.recommend.year" min="1" max="3" type="number">
</div>
</div>
<div class="c-form-group ng-scope" ng-if="data.answer_taxi">
<label class="c-option c-option--right u-px u-py-sm u-clearfix ng-scope" ng-if="!rc.planA && !rc.prestige" ng-click="cc.utils.audit('recommendation_warranty_plan_taxi_b')">
<input class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-required" required="" ng-model="rc.recommend.warrantyPlan" value="taxiB" name="warrantyPlan" type="radio">
<i class="c-option__radio"></i>
Plan B Warranty (Taxi) & Breakdown Recovery
</label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="o-media c-card c-card__block u-shadowed u-mb-lg u-text-body u-bg-success" ng-if="!rc.prevVap() && rc.VapEligible ">
<div class="c-form-group">
<label class="c-form-control-label u-px u-py-sm u-w-100">Vehicle Asset Protection Options:</label>
<label class="c-option c-option--right u-px u-py-sm u-clearfix" ng-click="cc.utils.audit('recommend_vap')">
<input class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-required" required="" ng-model="rc.recommend.vapPlan.plan" value="standard" name="vapPlan" type="radio">
<i class="c-option__radio"></i>
Vehicle Asset Protection - Standard Cover
</label>
<label class="c-option c-option--right u-px u-py-sm u-clearfix ng-scope" ng-if="data.answer_equity == true" ng-click="cc.utils.audit('recommend_negative_equity')">
<input class="ng-untouched ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" ng-model="rc.recommend.vapPlan.equity" name="vapPlanEquity" type="checkbox" style="">
<i class="c-option__checkbox"></i>
Negative Equity Cover
</label>
<label class="c-option c-option--right u-px u-py-sm u-clearfix" ng-click="cc.utils.audit('vap_key_facts_checked')">
<input class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-required" required="" ng-model="rc.recommend.vapCheck" name="vapCheck" type="checkbox">
<i class="c-option__checkbox"></i>
You confirm that you have received the VAP key facts leaflet?
</label>
</div>
</div>
</form>
<div class="c-form-group">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</main>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js">
<script src="./build/app.js?v=2.13" defer="">
<script src="/build/standalone/jspdf.js" defer="">
<script src="/build/standalone/sigWebTablet.js" defer="">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: remove `)` from 3rd and 4th xpath. After `class` and before `and`

Comment: well spotted, but still : "Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression"

Comment: There is another problem: 3rd and 4th xpath are `//label[@class,`. There is a comma `,` instead of equal `=` sign. Fix it :)

Comment: Your loop variable i is not right. you are inc i but you use i1 for loop

Comment: Rafal ... syntax now is correct :)

Comment: Do you really need to extract the text or is getting the state of the checkbox for these 4 items what you actually want? I'm confused.

Comment: I need the text as it is dynamic , dependent on questions from previous pages, but ultimately the state of the 2 radio buttons and the 2 checkboxes. 

As i will need to decide whether to check them or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused as to what you are trying to do. You mention getting the text from the elements and also getting the state of the checkboxes. Your XPaths on the outer and inner loop overlap. Your `elementz` list is pulled from a `LABEL` that contains the `c-option` class but then you start with an element from `elementz` and the first part of your XPath you repeat the search for a `LABEL` that contains the `c-option` class.

There is an much easier way to do this. Each of these checkboxes/radiobuttons are `INPUT` tags and have a `name` specific to their value.

Plan B Warranty (Taxi) & Breakdown Recovery: `<input ... name="warrantyPlan" type="radio">`

Vehicle Asset Protection - Standard Cover: `<input ... name="vapPlan" type="radio">`

Negative Equity Cover: `<input ... name="vapPlanEquity" type="checkbox" style="">`

You confirm that you have received the VAP key facts leaflet?: `<input ... name="vapCheck" type="checkbox">`

So with that info, you can just get each `INPUT` with CSS selectors like

```
By.cssSelector("input[name='warrantyPlan']")
```

Once you have the `INPUT` element, you can check if it's selected using `.isSelected()`.

If you really do need the text, you can get the label because it's the parent of the `INPUT` we just got. We can do this with an XPath, `By.xpath("..")`, which gets the parent of the current element.

We can put this all together like

```
// Plan B Warranty (Taxi) & Breakdown Recovery
WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='warrantyPlan']"));
System.out.println(e.isSelected()); // false
System.out.println(e.findElement(By.xpath("..")).getText()); // Plan B Warranty (Taxi) & Breakdown Recovery

// Vehicle Asset Protection - Standard Cover
e = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='vapPlan']"));
System.out.println(e.isSelected()); // false
System.out.println(e.findElement(By.xpath("..")).getText()); // Vehicle Asset Protection - Standard Cover
```

I just did the first two. You can see the pattern and apply it for the last two.

Comment: That has solved my overcomplicated solution.

All now working, text and test for selected ... :-)